# How to run bash script on ssh authentication failed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

How to run a `bash script` on ssh authentication failed?
I need to notify end user that someone tries to login in his machine?

Something like : $RHOST + $(date)

Where should I put my bash script and how can I get values as **IP**, **USERNAME** from where request comes?

Comment: Consider setting up fail2ban to send emails.

Comment: @user000001 I don't have to send emails instead of that I invoke `curl -X GET 'htpp://example.com'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need grep /var/log/auth.log and notify by email